# Are there any mature Cookie based HttpSession implementations?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, servlets, playframework, httpsession

I want to use a cookie based HttpSession in a serlvet container. All session data should be stored inside the cookie. It seems to be uncommon within servlet applications. In [Rails (Session)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html) and [Playframework (Session)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSessionFlash), this kind of session handling is the default. Why is this so uncommon?

In concrete I need a solution for JBoss EAP6 (without session scoped beans). I found two implementations based on serlvet filters:

- [Stateless Servlet Filter](http://statelessfilter.sourceforge.net/) "This filter is still in a beta status." 2013
- [java-stateless-http-session](https://github.com/lawrence0819/java-stateless-http-session) No references for usage and no commit for more than a year. No tests.

Do you know any alternatives?

(If possible I don't want want to discuss pros and cons in general)

Comment: You might want to clarify that you mean that the session is **stored** in the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

It is uncommon in Java EE to have session data persisted in cookie ... because `HttpSession` is implemented in all servlet containers.

In cookie persistent sessions, you have a limit in size, and you must use signed data to avoid manipulation of session client side. You must crypt data if you want to keep sensitive informations in session. And all session data is exchanged with every request and response. Those limits go away with `HttpSession`.

The highest interest of cookie persistent sessions is that you can have a farm of multiple servers that can respond to any request, because the session is contained in the request. But this can be done in Java EE by using *sticky sessions* at a reverse proxy level (because you have reverse proxies in almost every serious data center) : the reverse proxies know about the session and pass a request to the server that holds it.

Some Java EE servers have even a notion of shared sessions.

IMHO it is not that is would be very hard to implement a cookie persistent session in Java, it is simply that for professional usages, it has not been found as important enough.

Comment: I know that HttpSession is usually implemented **by** the servlet container. The question is more why they don't provide an cookie based implementation as an alternative.
I don't want to discuss the general pros and cons here. There are more than you mentioned. 
Almost all JavaEE server provide some kind of session replication and I know about sticky sessions. But that is not my question.
Implementing signatures and encryption by myself is something I try to avoid.

Comment: As I'm not myself a servlet container programmer, the following is only my opinion, but I think because major servlet container developpers did not find it useful enough. And users of those containers did not ask for it as an important feature.